# android studio disable optimising imports automatically

Tags: android, android-studio

I had a few unused imports in Java file which were not used. Android Studio suggested me to "**Optimize unused imports automatically on the fly**" I clicked on it.

Now all the unused imports are removed automatically. Is there a way to revert this settings?

I am new to android so please forgive me if i missed something simple.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try to disable:

> File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import | Optimize imports on the fly.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I am using Mac where the option was under AndroidStudio>Preferences>Editor>General>Auto Import. But anyway couldn't have found it without your help.

Comment: This answer is correct, but wasn't working for me, because I had a mixed-language project, and had forgotten to change: Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Kotlin > Imports

Comment: Thank you @EdmundJohnson! can we add that to the answer?

Comment: @jeffski13 You are welcome to add that to the answer.  I would rather not as I can no longer remember the details of this question.

Answer (score 2):

File > Settings > Editor > General >Auto Import (Mac: Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > General >Auto Import).

Uncheck check boxes and set Insert imports on paste to None. Unambiguous imports are now added automatically to your files.

[Reference](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/content/en/Unit%201/11_p_hello_world.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or better: Shift + rearrange-code-shortkey)

Edit: Ah, oh, thought you mean the import cleanup in combination with code rearrangement. Well, if someone has trouble with import cleanup while code rearrangement, use my answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

**For Flutter/Dart:**

Setting > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter

[image]